# How can I invite users to a chat room?

Tags: support, chat

Adrian helped set up a [Marketing Cloud chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58667/marketing-cloud), which is great, however I would like to invite users to join it. I thought I could do this by mentioning others. I've tried following instructions [on this faq page](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq) which states:

> You can only mention @someone who has been in the room at some point. If you need to invite someone to your room, do it from the user's chat profile page or from the user card that pops up when you click on their avatar in a chat room.

I can't locate either of these (the user's chat profile page or the user card). Please can someone point me in the right direction to invite people to a chat room?

Oh, and I've also tried assigning 'Explicit write access', but this does not appear to do anything; probably due to the fact that users already have a high reputation.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to search for folks in the [users](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users) tab and find people's user card that way. For instance, my chat profile would be: http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/92318/adrian-larson

Comment: It appears that you can only search for users who have previously participated in a room discussion.

Comment: @EliotHarper Yes, unfortunately, it's a PITA to try to invite someone to a chat room unless they're in a thread you're posting in.

Comment: @Eliot If you email me the user names I can try to super ping them.

Comment: @crmprogdev I am trying to invite someone in a thread to chat but cant figure it out. Can you please advise?

Comment: Data_Kid @AdrianLarson can use his moderator super powers to ping them for you. Otherwise, if there are enough comments in the thread, when the prompt appears, you can answer "yes" when asked, "Let's discuss this further in Chat?" (or something similar). You can also ask the user in that thread if they'd like to discuss in chat by posting an at message to them in the thread with a link to the room you create in chat (name the room for you and the other user). They'll be notified of your at message and will hopefully respond in chat. Those are the only ways I know of.